# Having Trouble with Force.com REST API oAuth2 Authentication

Tags: force.com, rest, php, rest-service, curl

I am experimenting with Pat_Patterson's "[Interact with the Force.com REST API from PHP](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php)". I am using PHP Version 5.6.3 , and I already registered my app via Setup->Create->Apps->Connected Apps. I setup the Redirect URL, Customer Secrets and Consumer Keys in the Config.php file but when I run the code it gives me an error:

> **Error: call to token URL https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token failed with status 0, response , curl_error SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate, curl_errno 60**

Can someone explain what this error means and what steps are necessary to address it?

Comment: Have you tried with a different tool (like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/features))? It's hard to tell whether this is an issue with curl or an issue with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Probably way too late, but I suspect you don't have a proper SSL certificate on your server. You can set curl option verify_peer to false and it should fix this rerror.